# I have one array in mongoDb want to populate the ids of that array using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection containing documents with an embedded array of products. Each product is represented by an productId, brandId, packSizeId, competitorId, and other related fields. I want to populate the products array with detailed information from different collections by performing lookups. The goal is to create a new structure where each product contains information such as the product name, brand name, and other details, like this:

```
{
  products: [
    {
      productId: "SomeProductId1",
      brandId: "SomeBrandId1",
      packSizeId: "SomePackSizeId1",
      competitorId: "SomeCompetitorId1",
      potential: "Potential1"
    },
    {
      productId: "SomeProductId2",
      brandId: "SomeBrandId2",
      packSizeId: "SomePackSizeId2",
      competitorId: "SomeCompetitorId2",
      potential: "Potential2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to populate the 'products' array with detailed information for each product, brand, and other fields by performing lookups on different collections

Here's the MongoDB aggregation pipeline I've created to achieve this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "products.productId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "productsArray.product"
    }
  },
])
```

The $project stage is optional but recommended to reshape the output. Here, you can specify which fields you want to include in the final result and rename them as needed.
In the provided code, it projects the productId and brandId with their corresponding names. You should replace "productName" and "brandName" with the actual field names from the "products" and "product_brands" collections

`I am expecting`

```
products : [
{
productId : "product Name"
brandId: "Brand Name"
},
{
productId : "product Name"
brandId: "Brand Name"
},
]
```

Comment: I got the resolution on this, productId this is stored as a string that's why lookup is not working I have update the code while creating the list as productId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(productId) and my issue get resolved. 

Thank you